# Eclipse C won't show any errors

Tags: c, eclipse, settings

I setup Eclipse for C today and I'm kinda struggling.Eclipse will not show any errors and I get Binary not found error from time to time.Example code:

```
int main(void){
int a = "str";
printf("%d" + a);
return 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what eclipse looks like : http://prntscr.com/ls6hxq .
I even get weird highlights in random places.The settings are all over the place right now.Is there any settings examples available for me to copy?If not which settings should i tweak so I at least can get the most basic errors and remove the annoying highlighting?

Comment: what are you expecting this: `printf("%d" + a);` to output?  what are you expecting: `int a = "str";` to place in the variable `a`?

Comment: in eclipse, you need, as part of the setup, to not only select the compiler but to also supply the options to that compiler

Comment: Im expecting eclipse to show the errors in the mentioned lines.Like red lines or something,now it does nothing.I can write an essay in there and it will probably not show any syntax errors

Comment: eclipse doesn't know anything about the syntax of a language.  That is why you need to select the compiler AND supply the options to that compiler.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to accomplish the same functionality

Comment: Yeah i get it,i lost you at the options,what do i need to do exactly?I use MinGw

Comment: I don't know the options for `MinGw`.  Suggest reading the available (online) manual for the available options